# How to extract color features via histogram from a masked image?

Tags: python, opencv, background-color, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I extracted an object from an image, so now I have [a masked image with a tennis ball and a black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fk43.png).

I want to extract the color features from the tennis ball alone via a histogram. This is the code I have so far, but by the looks of the histogram, the black background dominates the any of the other colors, which makes the histogram ineffective:

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

# Import image and convert to gray
image = Image.open("res_300.png")
im = image.convert('L')
im_array = array(im)

# Create a new figure
figure()
gray()

# Show contours with origin upper left corner
contour(im, origin='image')
axis('equal')
axis('off')

# Create histogram
figure()
hist(im_array.flatten(), 128)
show()
```

Is there a way to draw the histogram from the tennis ball BGR color features while disregarding the black background?

I'm a python rookie. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the color channels into `BGR`, we can use `cv2.split()` then use [`cv2.calcHist()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html) to extract the color features with a histogram. To remove the dominant black background, we can set the range to `[1, 256]`.

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')

channels = cv2.split(image)
colors = ("b", "g", "r")

plt.figure()
plt.title("Color Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("# of Pixels")
features = []

# Loop over the image channels (B, G, R)
for (channel, color) in zip(channels, colors):

    # Calculate histogram
    hist = cv2.calcHist([channel], [0], None, [255], [1, 256])
    features.extend(hist)

    # Plot histogram
    plt.plot(hist, color = color)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `np.histogram` that does so as well. And similar to nathancy's answer, one can set limit from `1` to ignore the black background:

```
image = cv2.imread('8fk43.png')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

for i, c in zip(range(3), 'bgr'):
    hist,bins = np.histogram(image[:,:,i], bins=range(0,256))

    plt.plot(bins[1:-1], hist[1:], c=c)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** The above approach is somewhat incorrect. Think about the pure green `(0,255,0)` will be overlooked at the red/blue channels. The correct way would be masking the tennis ball first, and pass the mask into `np.histogram` as weights.

For example, in this case, one can simply take `mask` as where all the channels are non-zero:

```
mask = (image>0).sum(-1)
mask = np.array(mask>0, dtype=np.uint8)
```

which gives mask:

[image]

And then,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

for i, c in zip(range(3), 'bgr'):
    hist,bins = np.histogram(image[:,:,i], bins=range(0,256), weights=mask)

    plt.plot(bins[:-1], hist, c=c)

plt.show()
```

gives a more reasonable histogram with respect to the actual size of the ball:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could neglect/remove low intensity value (corresponding to black) from all 3 RGB channels. Then take a mean in all 3 channels to get the corresponding RGB value of the desired object.